# how sort the map data as per the likes_count in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-native, mapping

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
let comments = [{body: "good", like_count: 2},
             {body: "bad article", like_count: 0}, 
             {body: "great", like_count: 4}];
this.state = { comments };
render() {
 return(
  { comments.map((comment, index) =>
   <Text>{comment.body}</Text>
  )}
 );
};
```

Here is the code, I want to map the data as per the like_count, I want comment with maximum like count on top and i want to print the whole comments like this.

How can I add the condition for this map.
My output will be:  body: "great", like_count: 4,
                    body: "good", like_count: 2,
                    body: "bad article", like_count: 0

Please suggest the solution if anyone know, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let comments = [
   {body: "good", like_count: 2},
   {body: "bad article", like_count: 0}, 
   {body: "great", like_count: 4}
];

let sortedComments = comments.sort((a, b) => a.like_count < b.like_count)
```

sortedComments will be:

```
[
   { body: 'great', like_count: 4 },
   { body: 'good', like_count: 2 },
   { body: 'bad article', like_count: 0 }
]
```

Comment: Note that [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the original array, if you want a new array add `.slice()` before `sort`.